# POSTGRES: INNER JOIN 1:N com várias tabelas. Preciso contar e mostrar registros que foram acessados como uma lista

Tags: postgresql, query, inner-join

Preciso contar registros da tabela `acesso_registro` e mostrar em uma lista.

Schema:

```
acesso_registro
+--------------+--------+------------+
|id_tipo_midia |id_midia| data_acesso| 
+--------------+--------+------------+
|01            | 03     | 2019-06-03 |
|01            | 03     | 2019-06-03 |
|03            | 01     | 2019-06-05 |
|02            | 03     | 2019-06-06 |
|02            | 01     | 2019-06-06 |
|03            | 02     | 2019-07-08 |
+--------------+--------+------------+

tipo_midia
+--+-------+
|id| tipo  |
+----------+
|01| Vídeo |
|02| Audio |
|03| Imagem|
|04| Outro |
+----------+

videos
+--+----------+
|id| titulo   |
+-------------+
|01| video_01 |
|02| video_02 |
|03| video_03 |
|04| video_04 |
+-------------+

audios
+--+----------+
|id| titulo   |
+-------------+
|01| audio_01 |
|02| audio_02 |
|03| audio_03 |
|04| audio_04 |
+-------------+

imagens
+--+-----------+
|id| titulo   |
+--------------+
|01| imagem_01 |
|02| imagem_02 |
|03| imagem_03 |
|04| imagem_04 |
+--------------+
```

A query deve me retornar:

```
*---------*---------*--------*
|tipoMidia| titulo  | acessos|
*---------*---------*--------*
|vídeo    |video_03 | 2      |
|Imagem   |imagem_01| 1      |
|Imagem   |imagem_02| 1      |
|Audio    |audio_01 | 1      |
|Audio    |audio_03 | 1      |
*---------*---------*--------*
```

Obs: A tabela `acesso_registro` incrementa uma linha sempre que uma mídia é acessada. O banco de dados que eu uso é Postgres.

Comment: Você quer dizer que vai decidir com qual tabela deverá fazer a junção de acordo com o conteúdo do campo id_tipo_midia da tabela acesso_registro?

Comment: Isso! Veja que na tabela `acesso_registro`, as duas primeiras linhas mostram que há dois registros para o tipo de mídia "Vídeo" da tabela `tipo_midia` e que esses dois registros é o `id` 03 da tabela `videos`, ou seja, o  "video_03".

Comment: Prá que simplificar se você pode complicar!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente utilizar UNION para as junções de cada tipo de mídia:

```
SELECT tipoMidia, titulo, acessos FROM (
    (SELECT  tipo_midia.tipo, videos.titulo, COUNT(acesso_registro.data_acesso) AS acessos
            FROM acesso_registro INNER JOIN tipo_midia ON (acesso_registro.id_tipo_midia = tipo_midia.id) 
                                        INNER JOIN videos ON (acesso_registro.id_midia = videos.id)
            WHERE tipo_midia.tipo = 'video'
            GROUP BY 1, 2)
    UNION
    (SELECT  tipo_midia.tipo, audios.titulo, COUNT(acesso_registro.data_acesso) AS acessos 
            FROM acesso_registro INNER JOIN tipo_midia ON (acesso_registro.id_tipo_midia = tipo_midia.id) 
                                        INNER JOIN audios ON (acesso_registro.id_midia = audios.id)
            WHERE tipo_midia.tipo = 'audio'
            GROUP BY 1, 2)
    UNION
    (SELECT  tipo_midia.tipo, imagens.titulo, COUNT(acesso_registro.data_acesso) AS acessos 
            FROM acesso_registro INNER JOIN tipo_midia ON (acesso_registro.id_tipo_midia = tipo_midia.id) 
                                        INNER JOIN imagens ON (acesso_registro.id_midia = imagens.id)
            WHERE tipo_midia.tipo = 'imagem'
            GROUP BY 1, 2)
);
```

Desconsiderando todos em que o tipo_midia seja 'outro'.